# Customize build of Java WAR for different customers using same code base

Tags: java, maven, build, customization

We have a code base for a Java EE application that is customized for different customers. The customization is realized at runtime. The application is bootstrapped by a factory class that reads the configuration parameters from JNDI, detects the customer and builds the customized components.

One drawback of this approach is that the application always contains the code for all customers (e. g. label files for different customers, where a button is labeled for customer A as "Decline" and for customer B as "Reject", but also parts with customer-specific logic).

Another drawback is that customer A can use customer B's configuration parameters and use the application version designed for customer B.

Is it possible to set the customer during build time and not at runtime? The result of each build should be some our-app-customer-X.war 
Our build system is maven.

Comment: Is you customization only based on configuration somethings like property files etc. ?

Comment: No, not purely file-based: if JNDI-parameter customer=A, my bootstrapping method maps REST-end-point /resources to  new CustomerAResourcesEndpoint() where the class CustomerAResourcesEndpoint is a class that was requested by customer A.

Comment: Can you make a more concrete example of your scenario?